# Incorrect Syntax near 'Contribution'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I developed a Java application with MS SQL Server 2008 as database. I am using the JDBC drivers available on Microsoft's website.

It was working fine till now. But as the load increased, a lot of SQLServerException appeared.

The query is

```
 INSERT INTO ANSWERS VALUES ('pd','GK002','A','B','','','Yes','QUIZ012')
```

The exception is

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Contribution'.
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:633)
   at nina.dbinterface.FinalDBInteraction.updateUserAnswers(FinalDBInteraction.java:93)
   at nina.dbinterface.FinalDBInteraction.updateDatabase(FinalDBInteraction.java:43)
   at nina.user.ui.MainWindow.submitQuiz(MainWindow.java:1032)
   at nina.user.ui.MainWindow.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:917)
```

I am not using the word 'Contribution' anywhere in my query. Then why this error? Any solutions?

Comment: Anything called "Contribution" in your database? Any trigger on the Answers table?

Comment: I this the actual query that caused the exception? I suspect sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running a [profiler trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) to capture the SQL batches being executed against the database at a time when these errors are occurring.

Without knowing exactly how the command is being sent to SQL Server (e.g. a stored proc, in-line SQL in the app, using an ORM or some other "middle-ware", dynamic SQL, etc) it's difficult to give an answer.

Cheers,
Dave